# Celery Jobs saves Data wrong or to much

Tags: python, celery

i have a celery job to fetch some Crypto-Rates-Data from coinmarketcap.com.
If the job as been triggert several times, i dont have 100 results at my Database, i always got 101-108 records. Why that?

tasks.py

```
def get_exchange_rate():
    api_url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=100"
    try:
        exchange_rates = requests.get(api_url).json()
        for exchange_rate in exchange_rates:
            CryptoPrices.objects.update_or_create(
                key=exchange_rate['id'],
                symbol=exchange_rate['symbol'],
                defaults={
                    "market_cap_usd": round(float(exchange_rate['market_cap_usd']), 3),
                    "volume_usd_24h": round(float(exchange_rate['24h_volume_usd']), 3),
                    "value": round(float(exchange_rate['price_usd']), 2)
                })
        logger.info("Crypto rate(s) updated successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

is there any way of limiting the max entries at the DB for this table?
In the end i want to have exactly 100

regards

Answer (score 0):

You're relying on the ordering of the coinmarket cap feed to be consistent. Since it ranks by marketcap it will drop coins on and off the bottom of the list, and since you're using update_or_create() new entries will be created and old ones left hanging.

If you want to track the top 100 yourself, then I'd suggest you get the top 150 and do your own/ordering filtering. Alternatively add an update time to your model (auto_now=True) and after updating delete anything over a certain age.

Comment: Can't i simply overwrite the old ones and take only the 100 from my query at the url of the api - ?limit=100?

Comment: @venom you have 2 options if you absolutely only ever want 100 rows into the table (both are suboptimal). Delete everything before you start or track which ones are updated and delete the rest after update. A super awful way would be to use the ranking as the PK, but that will likely break your other queries in interesting ways.